# Prove if angle bisectors of a pair of opposite angles of quad. meet on diagonal made by remaining points then the remaining points will do same

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

In a quadrilateral $ABCD$, the bisectors of $\angle A$ and $\angle C$ meet on $BD$, prove that the bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle D$ meet on $AC$.

Just give a hint in comments first please. If I fail to get the answer then I will tell you and then give the answer.

Comment: Hint: [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)

Comment: @achillehui Thanks my dude I got the answer, I will post it please comment whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
In quadrilateral $ABCD$, bisector of $\angle A$ meets $BD$ at $F$, bisector of $\angle B$ meets $AC$ at $E$, bisector of $\angle C$ meets $BD$ at $I$, bisector of $\angle D$ meets $AC$ at $G$.

By angle bisector theorem,
$$\frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{BF}{FD}$$
$$\frac{BC}{CD}=\frac{BI}{ID}$$
Now, for the condition given to be true 
$F=I$
Therefore, 
$$\frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{BC}{CD}$$
By rearranging it we get, 
$$\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{AD}{CD}$$
which again by angle bisector theorem means, 
$$\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AG}{GC}$$
This implies $G=E$ thus proving our statement.

Comment: +1 this proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks my dude. Love the community here.